# Paypal Braintree integration with recurring payments

Tags: php, paypal, braintree

How I can implementing recurring payments in Paypal Braintree
I have already implemented normal ontime payment with it, now I require to implement recurring payments too.

I follow this 
Client-side
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/#1-set-up-your-client

Server-side
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/#2-set-up-your-server-to-call-the-braintree-sdk

**I am using Sandbox account of PayPal**

Please guide me, how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal Checkout via Braintree is for one-time payments, not recurring payments.

For recurring payments, you have two options:

1) Integrate the [PayPal Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) directly, without Braintree

2) Upgrade to a full [Braintree Direct Gateway account](https://www.braintreepayments.com/country-selection). This requires business approval by the Braintree PayPal service.